# Can wife marry husband’s elder brother?

Tags: halal-haram

Can a widow or divorcee marry husband’s elder brother?  Is it permissible to do?

Comment: Just give me an answer in yes or no. Please.

Comment: If you want to ask questions and get yes or nor as an answer you shouldn't ask in a Q&A site in first place. Please read the suggested duplicate post and tell us what you miss and why?